# <input type="range" v-model="state"> is writing a `string` to my `number` model with no TypeScript error (Vue3/JSX)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, jsx, tsx

I'm using Vue 3 with TypeScript and JSX (not Vue `<template>`s). When I use a `<input type="range">` like this to edit a model:

```
export default defineComponent({

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const state = ref(123)

    return () => {
      <input type="range" v-model="state">
    }
  });
}
```

I don't get a type error at compile time. When I run the code, editing the range input will change `state` from storing a `number` to storing a `string` value, violating the safety checks I'm meant to get from TypeScript and causing bugs elsewhere.

1. How can I make this show a type error at compile-time?
2. How can I fix this so only numbers are written to `state`?

I tried using `v-model.number` but this doesn't seem available in JSX?

My current workaround is to add

```
onInput={() => { state = parseFloat(String(state)); }
```

to do the conversion. This is error prone though, plus I'm not sure if watchers or anything might see the `string` version of the model before I convert it to a `number`.

Edit: If it makes a difference, I'm using default Vite settings to build this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [jsx plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-jsx) plugin you could do something like :

```html
<input v-model={[state, ['number']]} />
```